# If a class does not inherit from E or V can it still be used in graph queries in OrientDB 2.2?

Tags: orientdb

If I create a document class that does not inherit from E (edge) or V (vertex) is it still possible to give members of this class relationships/links and use them in graph queries?

For context, I have a class which inherits from nothing. Currently I am using it as a simple key-value store, but I am concerned that later I may have "painted myself into a corner" if I want to add relationships do more complex graph-style queries involving it.

Comment: Which OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.2.33, though can upgrade to 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB 3.0 introduce Multi-Model API, with this Java API, you can use OrientDB as a Document-Graph Database, allowing you to work with Vertices, Edges or simple Documents. This means that with ODatabaseDocument instances you can query documents, but also graphs, without the need for an additional API.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-API.html

Hope it helps

Regards